# Program crashes when the destructor of an std::fstream object that was passed to a shared library function

Tags: c++, boost, dll, shared-libraries, dllimport

I have a shared library.

A function is declared in it, which takes a functor as a parameter. This functor returns an object of type `std::fstream`.

In the body of the function, the functor is called and data is written to the received stream, after which the function finishes.

However, as I saw in the debugger, during the call of the destructor of the `std::fstream` object an error occurs, causing the program to crash. This error occurs only when compiling under Windows.

This destructor error does not occur if the `std::fstream` object is not created explicitly in a dynamic library function, but rather with the passed functor.

A minimal reproducible example is below:

### `lib.cpp`

```
#define BOOST_DLL_FORCE_ALIAS_INSTANTIATION
#include <fstream>
#include <function>
#include <boost/dll/alias.hpp>

void BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE func (std::function<std::fstream()> file_generator) {
    auto file = file_generator();
    file << "test" << std::endl;
}

BOOST_DLL_ALIAS( func, plugin)
```

This function receives a functor that returns an object of type std::fstream and writes plain text to the resulting file.

##### CMake file to compile the shared library

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(lib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)


add_library(lib SHARED lib.cpp)
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
```

#### `main.cpp`

```
#include <boost/dll.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <function>

typedef void (create_t)(std::function<std::fstream()>);

int main() {
    auto func = boost::dll::import_alias<create_t>("lib.dll", plugin);
    func([](){ return std::fstream("file.txt", std::ios::out);});
}
```

##### CMake file to compile the main program:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(TestingCore)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_executable(TestingCore main.cpp)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
```

In this case the file is created correctly and the text is written to it correctly, the program crashes on the stream destructor.

Comment: I'm a bit out of my depth here but returning a non-POD (or even PODs in some cases) by value from a shared library, handing over its destruction to the caller, seems risky. You want the same allocator that created the thing to also destroy the thing. The definition of _the thing_ on both sides must be _exactly_ the same for the destruction to work if you hand over ownership over the DLL boundaries (says my gut feeling).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I link both files with the same version of the standard library, so the definition and implementation of std::fstream should be the same

Comment: @IanGaspariunas if some aspect of libraries are statically linked, often global data structures are duplicated. The effect may be undefined behaviour even if binary compatibility was fine (e.g. deleting an object from the wrong heap won't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the object is created and used within the function passed as a functor, it is likely that its destructor is called within the same scope and memory space as where it was created. However, when the object is created explicitly within the shared library function, it may be destroyed in a different scope or memory space than where it was created, leading to memory access errors and program crashes.

The only more or less convenient solution I have found so far is to change the logic of the program a bit.

The std::fstream object itself should be created within a dynamic library function, and the file should be opened using the passed functor.

```
void BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE func (std::function<void(std::fstream&)> file_generator) {
    std::fstream file;
    file_generator(file);
    file << "test" << std::endl;
}


typedef void (create_t)(std::function<void(std::fstream&)>);

int main() {
    auto func = boost::dll::import_alias<create_t>("lib.dll", plugin);
    func([](std::fstream& file){ file.open("file.txt", std::ios::out);});
}
```

Comment: When you say _"it may be destroyed in a different scope"_, do you mean _"it may be destroyed by a different allocator"_ or similar? I don't see where _scope_ comes in here since it's returned by value and RVO kicks in.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I mean something like a different address space. I don't fully understand how the address space of a dynamic windows library is mapped to a process address space. This problem only occurs with classes that have a virtual destructor. Maybe the destructor pointer in the virtual function table std::fatream is valid for the main process, but is not the correct address to call from the dynamic library?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Just in case I put the object containing the virtual functions in shared memory, for example, obviously calling them from the reading process would be wrong. Although the dynamic library functions are also executed in the same process, maybe there's still some similar address space problem?